# Parse XML file containing umlaute using SAX parser

Tags: java, android, xml, saxparser

I have looked through a lot of posts regarding the same problem, but i can't figure it out. I trying to parse a XML file with umlauts in it. This is what i have now:

```
File file = new File(this.xmlConfig);
InputStream inputStream= new FileInputStream(file);
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"UTF-8");

InputSource is = new InputSource(reader);
is.setEncoding("UTF-8");

saxParser.parse(is, handlerConfig);
```

But it won't get umlauts properly. Ä,Ü and Ö will be only weird characters. The file is definitely in utf-8 and it is declared as such with the first line like this: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First rule: Don't second guess the encoding used in the XML document. Always use byte streams to parse XML documents:

```
InputStream inputStream= new FileInputStream(this.xmlConfig);
InputSource is = new InputSource(inputStream);
saxParser.parse(is, handlerConfig);
```

If that doesn't work, the `<?xml version=".." encoding="UTF-8" ?>` (or whatever) in the XML is wrong, and you have to take it from there.

Second rule: Make sure you *inspect* the the result with a tool that supports the encoding used in the target, or result, document. Have you?

Third rule: Check the byte values in the source document. Bring up your favourite HEX editor/viewer and inspect the content. For example, the letter `Ä` should be the byte sequence `0xC3 0x84`, if the encoding is UTF-8.

Forth rule: If it doesn't *look* correct, always suspect that the UTf-8 source is viewed, or interpreted, as an ISO-8859-1 source.  Verify this by comparing the first and second byte from the UTF-8 source with the [ISO 8859-1 code charts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Codepage_layout).

**UPDATE:**

The byte sequence for the UNICODE letter `ä` (latin small letter a with diaresis, U+00E4) is  `0xC3 0xA4` in the UTF-8 encoding.  If you use a viewing tool that only understands (or is configured to interpret the source as) ISO-8859-1 encoding, the first byte, `0xC3`is the letter `Ã`, and the second byte is the letter `¤`, or currency sign (Unicode U+00A4), which may look like a circle.

Hence, the "TextView" thingy in Android is interpreting your input as an ISO-8859-1 stream. I have no idea if it is possible to change that or not. But if you have your parsing result as a String or a byte array, you could convert that to a ISO-8859-1 stream (or byte array), and then feed it to "TextView".

Comment: The line is now `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>` and i changed to the byte stream from your answer. I also installed a hex viewer and found the byte sequence C3 A4 for small ä which seems to be alright according to what I've found to utf-8. The result of the parsing is shown in a TextView in android. I did set this manually to an ä at it worked. The parsing result though showed a big A with a ~ one top and a circle next to it. Any further ideas? Thank you very much

Comment: Finally i found the problem. The XML file did run through another process on an other part of the application that changed the encoding. Nearly gone mad on this. Thank you very much.

Comment: You're not the first one: "O, that way madness lies; let me shun that;
No more of that" ;-)